# Java - JVM - is there a way switch off capability of different JVMs sharing code loaded in memory?

Tags: java, jvm

I am troubleshooting an issue with a Java Desktop App running on a Citrix server which allows multiple users to run the app at the same time in their own Shared Desktop image.

When the application fails to find a class file throwing NoClassDefFoundError as expected and makes one user session to fail obviously. Then if another user connects to the same Citrix server via Shared Desktop image starting a separate JVM, this new session is also encountering the same NoClassDefFoundError.

It seems that JVMs are sharing code loaded in memory even though each user has its own JVM, as described in the SO question [what java virtual machine will do while executing multiple java applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12508951/what-java-virtual-machine-will-do-while-executing-multiple-java-applications)

Does anyone know if it's possible to turn off capability of different JVMs sharing code loaded in memory when these are in the same Citrix server?

Comment: The question you refer to is talking about shared native code, not shared Java code. Different JVMs will not share classloaders, so you've made a wrong assumption in your question. I recommend you concentrate on the exception, it's probably a lot simpler issue than you think.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's possible that I have done wrong assumption, I have limited access to actual Citrix server, however infrastructure guys have told that it's possible the JVM is running in Machine Context or in User Context, therefore if there is no way different JVMs can share loaded code in memory then this will pretty much confirm that there is only one JVM running in Machine context for all users connecting to the same Citrix server.

Comment: Yup, in a single JVM situation that seems a lot more plausible.

Comment: A StackOverflow question or answer is not an 'article'. Be precise.

Comment: Will keep that in mind